# how can i change define in php or what make instead

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

i have a language settings, the problem is that i can't change language on click, there is only two(2) files containing language settings, below is code that selects EN language

```
// ENGLISH TRANSLATION
select('APP_LANG', 'en');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN');

// FRENCH TRANSLATION
// define('APP_LANG', 'fr');
// setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
```

so i want to change language settings to french translation that is commented out, are there any possible way to toggle these languages?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquery and save your language strings in a constant along with the choices for languages in another constant. 
Define your index, then set the current language to the choices[index]
Define a global array to iterate that index through the choices and languages, calling on a function that uses a data attribute to display the desired language on click.

```js
const french = "Bonjour comment vas tu aujourd'hui? Voici une liste de textes que nous souhaitons traduire.";
const english = "Hello, how are you today? Here is a list of text we wish to translate.";
const languages = {'languages': {'en': english, 'fr': french} };
const choices = ['en', 'fr'];
let index = 0;
let currentLanguage = choices[index];

window.changeLanguage = function() {
    index = ++index % 2;
    currentLanguage = choices[index];
    translateLanguage();
}

function translateLanguage() {
    $("[data-lang]").each(function(){
        let key = $(this).data('lang');
        $(this).html(languages[key][currentLanguage] || "N/A");
    });
}

translateLanguage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeLanguage()">Translate to French</button>
<div data-lang="languages"></div>
```

Comment: it is different, it uses en.ini and fr.ini files i need to change `select('APP_LANG', 'en');` to `select('APP_LANG', 'fr');` with  onclick how can i do that?

Comment: the `select('APP_LANG', 'en')` is javascript yes?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use defined for this. I rather would save the language selection in a session like this:

```
session_start();
$lang = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "lang");

if (!empty($lang)) {
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
}

if (!empty($_SESSION["lang"])) {
    $_SESSION["lang"] = "en"; // set default
}
```

You can now call your php file like this:

index.php?lang=en    OR

index.php?lang=fr

Comment: it doesn't works below is code that throws errors `class Translate {

 public $lang;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->lang = (parse_ini_file("translations/". APP_LANG . ".ini", true)) ?: parse_ini_file("translations/en.ini", true);
 }

 public function t($var, $val=null) {
  $parts = explode('|', $var);
  if (!$val) {
   return $this->lang[$parts[0]][$parts[1]];
  }
  return str_replace("{{val}}", $val, $this->lang[$parts[0]][$parts[1]]);    
 }

}`

Comment: @buba Maybe you can use `parse_ini_file("translations/". $_SESSION["lang"]. ".ini", true)` instead of `parse_ini_file("translations/". APP_LANG . ".ini", true)`